# Test angular coreModule with a guard against reimport

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am unable to write test for a core module that has a guard defined in the constructor. My test fails with the requirement that parameters should be passed to constructor. If i pass it a reference to any module (AppModule), it gets treated as a reimport.

I just want to know how can a module with the following snippet in constructor be tested.

in my *core.module.ts* I have this -

```
 export class CoreModule {

  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptorService, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptorService, multi: true }
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried the TypeScript syntax for optional paramters?

```
constructor(parentModule?: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }
```

hope this helps